Where does Arrow’s Impossibility Theorem standard proof rely on the existence of at least three alternatives?
I am trying to understand the proof of the world-famous Arrow’s Impossibility Theorem. To do that, I have been relying on Wikipedia’s proof by decisive coalition, as well as on the proof provided by Amartya Sen in Sen & Maskin’s book “The Arrow Impossibility Theorem”. Arrow’s Theorem states the following:
If there are at least thee alternatives and the voter set is finite, there exists no social welfare function satisfying Pareto optimality, independence of irrelevant alternatives, unrestricted domain and non-dictatorship.
For the relevant definitions, see Wikipedia.
I can see that majority voting, in the presence of just two alternatives, satisfies all of Arrow’s conditions. What I cannot see is which steps in the proofs I quoted above rely on the existence of at least three alternatives.
Could anyone help me see which steps in the proofs mentioned above require the existence of at least three alternatives?

In the wiki page, the proof of the group contraction lemma starts with: ``Fix distinct $x$ , $y$ , $z$''. Clearly if there are only two alternatives, this is impossible to do.

@tdm, And even before that, the proof of the field expansion lemma starts with "Let $z$ be an outcome distinct from $x$, $y$."

@tdm Post your comment as an answer or close the Q?
